# Update object field of array in jsonb PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb, postgresql-json

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE resume (
  resume_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB
);
```

Inside that table I have a column `data` which has `JSONB` datatype and contains values like this:

```
{"educations": [{"major": "MAJOR-1", "minor": "MINOR-1"}, {"major": "MAJOR-2", "minor": "MINOR-2"}]}
```

Here is test data:

```
INSERT INTO resume VALUES('7e29d793-a4ba-4bfb-a93a-c2d34b7a5c8a', '{"educations": [{"major": "MAJOR-1", "minor": "MINOR-1"}, {"major": "MAJOR-2", "minor": "MINOR-2"}]}');
INSERT INTO resume VALUES('7e29d793-a4ba-4bfb-a93a-c2d34b7a5c8b', '{"educations": [{"major": "ANOTHER-MAJOR-1", "minor": "ANOTHER-MINOR-1"}, {"major": "ANOTHER-MAJOR-2", "minor": "ANOTHER-MINOR-2"}]}');
```

But now I need to turn major and minor values to array, so, for the first row I want to receive this result:

```
{"educations": [{"major": ["MAJOR-1"], "minor": ["MINOR-1"]}, {"major": ["MAJOR-2"], "minor": ["MINOR-2"]}]}
```

For the second row I want to receive this result:

```
 {"educations": [{"major": ["ANOTHER-MAJOR-1"], "minor": ["ANOTHER-MINOR-1"]}, {"major": ["ANOTHER-MAJOR-2"], "minor": ["ANOTHER-MINOR-2"]}]}
```

For now I have created this query to update `major`:

```
with sub as (
    select pos - 1 as elem_index, elem, resume_id
    from resume, jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'educations') with ordinality arr(elem, pos)
)
update resume cv
set data = jsonb_set(data, array['educations', sub.elem_index::text, 'major'], ('[' || (sub.elem -> 'major')::text || ']')::jsonb, true)
from sub
where cv.resume_id = sub.resume_id
```

But it updated only first element of array for all rows, so for now I receive this result:

```
{"educations": [{"major": ["MAJOR-1"], "minor": "MINOR-1"}, {"major": "MAJOR-2", "minor": "MINOR-2"}]}
{"educations": [{"major": ["ANOTHER-MAJOR-1"], "minor": "ANOTHER-MINOR-1"}, {"major": "ANOTHER-MAJOR-2", "minor": "ANOTHER-MINOR-2"}]}
```

So my question is how to fix this ?
Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 : jsonb updates based on `jsonb_set`**

`jsonb_set()` cannot makes several updates for the same jsonb data, so you need to create an `aggregate` function based on `jsonb_set()` and which will iterate on a set of rows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_set(x jsonb, y jsonb, p text[], z jsonb, b boolean)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$ SELECT jsonb_set(COALESCE(x, y), p, z, b) ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg(x jsonb, p text[], z jsonb, b boolean)
( SFUNC = jsonb_set
, STYPE = jsonb
) ;
```

Then you can use the aggregate function `jsonb_set_agg()` in the following query :

```
SELECT jsonb_set_agg(r.data, array['educations', (a.id - 1) :: text, b.key], to_jsonb(CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL THEN array[] :: text[] ELSE array[b.value] END), True)
  FROM resume AS r
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(r.data->'educations') WITH ORDINALITY AS a(data, id)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(a.data) AS b
 WHERE b.key = 'major' OR b.key = 'minor'
 GROUP BY resume_id
```

And finally within the update statement :

```
WITH sub AS (
SELECT jsonb_set_agg(r.data, array['educations', (a.id - 1) :: text, b.key], to_jsonb(CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL THEN array[] :: text[] ELSE array[b.value] END), True)
  FROM resume AS r
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(r.data->'educations') WITH ORDINALITY AS a(data, id)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(a.data) AS b
 WHERE b.key = 'major' OR b.key = 'minor'
 GROUP BY resume_id
)
UPDATE resume cv
   SET data = sub.data
  FROM sub
 WHERE cv.resume_id = sub.resume_id
```

**Solution 2 : break down and rebuild the jsonb data**

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(c.data ORDER BY c.id)
  FROM
     ( SELECT resume_id
            , a.id
            , jsonb_object_agg(b.key,to_jsonb(CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL THEN array[] :: text[] ELSE array[b.value] END)) AS data
         FROM resume AS r
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(r.data->'educations') WITH ORDINALITY AS a(data, id)
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(a.data) AS b
        GROUP BY resume_id, a.id
     ) AS c
 GROUP BY c.resume_id
```

see the test results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f6b02ac159f7f1ecd8b95e72e9245dcb).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. By the way is it possible to do this task without creating functions ?

Comment: Yes indeed. See the updated answer with the solution 2.

Comment: And one more thing, this updates other columns too, I mean that not only major and minor, but also other columns inside the educations, example: educations: [ { major: ['A'], created_at: [] } ], but actually I wanted to update only major and minor, is there a way to do this ?

Comment: In solution 1 you can add the clause `WHERE b.key = 'major' OR b.key = 'minor'` just before `GROUP BY resume_id`

Comment: Also `major` field could be `null`, and now after running first solution, I receive something like that: `major: [ null ]`, how can we avoid this and if `major` is `null` then turn it to empty array ?

Comment: I updated both solutions in the answer to manage the case where `{"major": null}` is transformed as `{"major":[]}`